# Background color becomes transparent when the style passed dynamically with TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a form where I pass the tailwind classes from a config for a button. For some reason background color doesn't get applied and button becomes transparent. I try with other classes (for example, I am able to make the button `rounded-full` from the same config) and  it works but only for background color, it seems not working.

```js
export function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

//submitButtonBackgroundColor comes from config

const submitButtonClasses = classNames(
  'mt-4 min-w-[10rem] rounded-md self-end px-4 py-2 text-sm font-bold text-white transition-opacity hover:opacity-90 active:opacity-100 disabled:opacity-50',
  submitButtonBackgroundColor === '' ? 'bg-[#65a30d]' : submitButtonBackgroundColor
)
```

User enters for example another arbitrary value as `bg-[#312e81]` and button becomes transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind needs to see a class in a string at **build time** for it to generate a CSS rule for said class. By the time a user enters a string in your app at **run time**, the CSS has already been built by Tailwind – it has done its part, the CSS generated, Tailwind is no longer doing anything.

`rounded-full` works because it has already been seen by Tailwind in another place in your app and thus its CSS rule exists.

Instead of having a user enter a Tailwind class, consider having them enter a valid `background-color` property value and use the `style` attribute:

```js
export function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

//submitButtonBackgroundColor comes from config

const submitButtonClasses = classNames(
  'mt-4 min-w-[10rem] rounded-md self-end px-4 py-2 text-sm font-bold text-white transition-opacity hover:opacity-90 active:opacity-100 disabled:opacity-50',
  submitButtonBackgroundColor === '' && 'bg-[#65a30d]'
);

// …

return (
  <button
    class={submitButtonClasses}
    style={{ backgroundColor: submitButtonBackgroundColor }}
  >
  </button>
);
```